# Two graphs from text files Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

How can I plot two graphs using the same axes from extracting the columns from text files?
I have two columns from two text files having values from 0-100.
I would like to plot two graphs(one for each text file) using the Matplotlib library. 
I am trying to use this code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plotfile('Book1.txt', delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1),
             names=('col1', 'col2'), marker='o')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Please guide

Comment: What does your data look like?  Please post a sample

Comment: See example 7 from the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/plotfile_demo.html), it shows how to plot multiple files on the same axes by using `newfig=False`

Comment: @anshanno: Data is like this  85.631812 90.9995
85.446494 90.8734
85.261176 90.7473
85.075858 90.6212
84.89054 90.4951
84.705222 90.369
84.40096336 90.2429
84.09670472 90.1168
83.79244608 89.9907
83.48818744 89.8646
83.1839288 89.7385
82.87967016 89.683872
82.57541152 89.6124
82.27115288 89.584059
81.96689424 89.4863
81.6626356 89.484246
81.35837696 89.384433
81.3413132 89.3602
81.32424944 89.28462
81.30718568 89.2341
81.29012192 89.184807
81.27305816 89.108
81.2559944 89.084994
81.23893064 88.985181
81.22186688 88.9819
81.20480312 88.885368
81.18773936 88.8558